# Extract cross-table duplicates not incl. table duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Imagine the following tables:

```
Table A:
x, y

Table B:
a, b
```

To find matches we will be performing the following query:

`SELECT A.x, B.a FROM A, B WHERE A.y = B.b`

However, `Table B` will contain duplicates *itself* and therefore the same `value` will match multiple times with the value (unique) in `Table A` how to avoid this?

**Edited**: An other acceptable answer if the above is impossible to do in a single query is to find all duplicates in `Table B` ignoring `Table A` and remove all of them except for *one*.

**Edit 2 as per request**:

`Table A`

```
col, 'hi'
col, 'bye'
col, 'lol'
col, 'teehee'
col, 'example'
```

`Table B`

```
col, 'hi'
col, 'hi'
col, 'bye'
col, 'hi'
col, 'bye'
col, 'example'
col, 'teehee'
col, 'lol'
col, 'hi'
```

Because there is multiple values `hi` and `bye` in `Table B` it will extract the value (col) in `Table A` multiple times which should be avoided since we're talking about 1000s of rows.

Comment: Please edit your question with *relevant* sample data and the results that you want.  As written, it is rather vague.

Comment: can you provide sample data and desired result

Comment: you could try distinct on combined with a join. something like SELECT DISTINCT ON(B.b) a.x,b.a FROM A JOIN B ON(A.y=B.b)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all rows from `A` and one arbitrary value from `B`, you have several options.  Most involve `group by` or `distinct`, which is rather expense.  The most performant method is probably to use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.a
        from b
        where A.y = B.b
        limit 1
       ) as b_a
from a;
```

For performance, you want an index on `b(b)`.